# How to convert JSON string with different value types to C# Dictionary?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2012, json.net

So, I want to convert this JSON string:

```
{
 "Posts" : 
    [
     {
       "Title" : "just a string",
       "Id" : "231"
     }, {
       "Title" : "Another string as title",
       "Id": "41"
     }
    ],
  "anotherKey" : "third string"
}
```

to C# Dictionary, but this code (using `Newtonsoft.Json` package; where `jsonString` is variable storing that JSON string):

```
Dictionary<string,Array> test1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Array>>(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine(test1.Count);
```

returns an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.Array. Path 'Posts', line 1, position 10.
```

Is another way how to convert this string to Dictionary?

Comment: The second entry isn't an array, it's a single string. Try deserializing to `Dictionary<string,object>` if you really want to mix single objects with collections, or `Dictionary<string,dynamic>`.

Comment: not really that i want to mix them, but it's part of JSON string from API not coded by me. But `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` works, so thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second entry isn't an array, it's a single string.

Try deserializing to `Dictionary<string,object>` or `Dictionary<string,dynamic>` to read all values.